# In Eclipse, I want to set a button's margin in the .java file (dynamically/programmatically)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062187/how-to-set-margin-dynamically-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981456/setting-buttons-margin-programmatically). Attempted to apply the post's answers, but the button remains without margins when I build and run the app. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ResultsActivityA extends Activity {

    Button button, submitButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //...
        LinearLayout activityResultsA= new LinearLayout(this);

        Button submitButton=new Button(this);

        LayoutParams dimensions= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        activityResultsA.setLayoutParams(dimensions);

        LayoutParams viewDimensions= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LayoutParams buttonDimensions= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        buttonDimensions.setMargins(50, 40, 0, 0);

        submitButton.setLayoutParams(buttonDimensions);

        activityResultsA.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        submitButton.setText("Home");
        submitButton.setId(5555);

        activityResultsA.addView(submitButton);

        setContentView(activityResultsA);
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Margins that you're expecting will be seen in lower density devices (ldpi) or medium density devices (mdpi) but not in higher density devices (hdpi, xxhdpi, ...).

`setMargins(top, left, bottom, right)` accepts int values in px unit. In your case, You're actually passing `50px`, `40px`, and `0px`.

You need to convert those values from `dp` to px

```
public static int convertDPtoPX(Context context, int dpValue) {

     DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

     return dpValue * displayMetrics.densityDpi;

}
```

Comment: I wrote this method in a class file and I called it in the layout .java file by writing "lt=cm.convertDPtoPX(this,50);", but "this" gives me an error. What should I be using instead?

Comment: You can put `getBaseContext()` or `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used getBaseContext() but it gives me the following error: 
The static method convertDPtoPX(Context, int) from the type ConvertMeasure should be accessed in a static way

Comment: I removed static from the method and this solves the problem.

Comment: When I build the app, the margin has not budged an inch (that is, it has not shifted left 50 dp).

Comment: Probably my calculation from dp to px returns incorrect value. Try calculations from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)

Comment: Tried their methods, same result. It seems to me that no matter what values I give to "buttonDimensions.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);", I still do not shift the margins(at all). What am I missing? I know this can be frustrating. What else can I do to center my button dynamically/programmatically?

Comment: Use [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#gravity). Alignment of Children of LinearLayout will be based on that gravity

Comment: I wrote "((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)submitButton.getLayoutParams()).gravity=Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;" after addView, but before setContentView and it centered the button.

Comment: Yes, that will work before calling `setContentView();`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote `((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)submitButton.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);` after `addView`, but before `setContentView` and it set the margins.